# Why Module::getOrInsertFunction returns a pointer to Constant

Tags: llvm

There are 4 variants like below for `Module::getOrInsertFunction` in LLVM and all of them returns `Constant*`. Why a pointer to `Constant` is returned for creating `Function`?

`Constant * getOrInsertFunction (StringRef Name, FunctionType *T, AttributeSet AttributeList)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a96581205e1149f5d70b56f9a83bc841a) reads:

> Four possibilities: 1. If it does not exist, add a prototype for the
>   function and return it. 2. If it exists, and has a local linkage, the
>   existing function is renamed and a new one is inserted. 3. Otherwise,
>   if the existing function has the correct prototype, return the
>   existing function. 4. Finally, the function exists but has the wrong
>   prototype: return the function with a constantexpr cast to the right
>   prototype.

For case 4, the return value with be a `ConstantExpr*`, not a `Function*`. Thus, the return type is `Constant*`, the common superclass.

Comment: What's the meaning of returned `ConstantExpr*` when prototype mismatch?

Comment: @Thomson Like the quoted passage says, it's a cast expression, casting the function that was found to the type you passed in.